# Regex del teclado en español?

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy usando la expresión regular de abajo para validar el registro de un password en un app, todo es con javascript, pero veo que no incluye todos los caracteres del teclado en español (`¿¡ñáéíóú...`).
Un ejemplo de una contraseña que quiero registrar es 'Reforma01¡' pero no la acepta, en cambio 'Reforma01!' si la acepta

Alguien tiene uno que incluya estos caracteres? o si solo debo agregarlos en el paréntesis de los caracteres especiales?

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/
```

Comment: Por favor, [edit] la pregunta e incluye un ejemplo de la contraseña que validas con esa expresión que deseas.

Comment: Ademas aclara el lenguaje.. no son exactamente iguales...

Comment: He registrado exitosamente 'Reforma01!' pero no me deja con 'Reforma01¡'; y el lenguaje es javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En principio, añadiendo `¡` (o cualquier otro carácter) y simplificando un poco con `\w` puede ser:

```
^(?=.*\w)(?=.*[@$¡!%*?&])[\w@$¡!%*?&]{8,}$
```

Hay otros intervalos disponibles para incluir otros carácteres especiales:

```
[A-zÀ-ú] // minúscula y mayúscula
[A-zÀ-ÿ] // como el anterior, incluyendo además letras con umlaut `¨` (incluye [ ] ^ \ × ÷)
[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ] // como el anterior, sin incluir [ ] ^ \
[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ] // como el anterior, sin incluir [ ] ^ \ × ÷
```

Sería entonces algo como

```
^(?=.*\w)(?=.*[@$¡!%*?&Á-ú])[\w@$¡!%*?&Á-ú]{8,}$
```

Basado en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26900132/236345).

La pregunta que te hicieron en los comentarios es importante, porque en Java hay otras opciones que acá desafortunadamente no se tienen.